# C++ constructor inherited?

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

In C++ constructors are not inherited.
However, I have this strange finding using clang12.
It compiles with C++17 following although it shouldn't.
If I use C++11 or C++14 it doesn't compile as I expected.

```
#include <iostream>

class Parent{
    int x_;
public:
    //Parent() = default;
    Parent(int const &x) : x_{x} {}
    void SayX(){ std::cout << x_ << std::endl; }
};
class Child : public Parent{
    // works with C++17 ff.
};
int main(){
    Child c {2};
    c.SayX();
    return 0;
}
```

--> Outputs 2 with C++17 ff., doesn't compile with C++11, 14

Answer (score 7):

You're not seeing an inherited constructor (you are right that these are opt-in through `using`), but aggregate initialization, which has indeed been extended in C++17 to cover base classes. From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) (emphasis mine):

> The *elements* of an aggregate are:
>
> - [...]
> - for a class, **the direct base classes in declaration order**, followed by the direct non-static data members that are neither anonymous bit-fields nor members of an anonymous union, in declaration order. <sub>(since C++17)</sub>

So `Child c {2};` copy-constructs its `Parent` subobject from `2`.